# Map checked cells from one sheet to others to summarize data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet that has customer information and another sheet where the customer information needs to go if it meets certain conditions. For example sheet one I have a customer with a unique identifier, and on sheet 2 I have several columns that could be checked off. If these columns are checked off I need those column headers to be populated into one cell in sheet 1. So

Sheet 1:

```
John Doe  019384388   Eats cookies 
                      Likes Movies
                      Needs Help from Stack exchange
```

Sheet 2:

```
Name     uniques identifier   Eats cookies   Likes movies Is tired Needs help 
John Doe 019384388               X             X                      X
```

This is just something I'm playing with at work to simplify some spreadsheets. I have worked with C, C++, and Java so I do understand condition statements and loops, but I haven't really worked with Google Apps Script / JavaScript. I am having a hard time knowing how to call to the individual cells in the spreadsheets to make condition statements, e.g.

```
if (box == "x" && unique id == "xxxxxx")
  cell ("Ai"(sheet1) = "Ai"(sheet2))
```

type things. Perhaps iterating through all the cells using a `for` loop that changes `i` until all cells are checked? Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: @Tim Williams, the OP is now using Excel formulas as a possibility. can you add back the Excel tag?

Comment: @MacroMarc - I'm not a fan of tagging questions which are specifically about google-spreadsheet with Excel, just because there's some overlap in the formula syntax (however large).  The question should be able to stand by itself under google-spreadsheet.  Anyone else is free to add back the tag if they feel it's appropriate.

Comment: OP, has anything helped so far?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom Google Apps function, and add an onedit trigger to it.:

```
function autoCheck(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName()=="Sheet2" && col >=3 && col<=5) {
     var str = "";
     for (i=3; i<=6; i++) {
        if (sheet2.getRange(row, i).getValue()=="X") {
           if (str.length==0) {
              str = sheet2.getRange(1, i).getValue();  
           } else {
             str =str + "\n" + sheet2.getRange(1, i).getValue();
           }
        }
     }
     sheet1.getRange(row, 3).setValue(str);
  }
}
```

Comment: Or you could use an Excel-style formula

Answer (score 1):

Add a row that concatenates the headers if the box is checked:

`=if(B1 = 'x', $A$1, '') & if(B2 = 'x', $A$2, '') & ...`

then vlookup() on the ID and return the concatenated field.

Add comma delimiters to the if statements if you want them, and hide the concatenated field if you don't want to see it in the table.

Comment: How do I nest the vlookup in the IF statement. Here is what I have: =IF('Sheet2!Q4 = "X",'Sheet2!Q3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!R4 = "X",'Sheet2!R3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!S4 = "X",'Sheet2!S3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!T4 = "X",'Sheet2!T3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!U4 = "X",'Sheet2!U3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!V4 = "X",'Sheet2!V3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!W4 = "X",'Sheet2!W3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!X4 = "X",'Sheet2!X3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!Y4 = "X",'Sheet2!Y3,"")&CHAR(10) & IF('Sheet2!Z4 = "X",'Sheet2!Z3,"")

Comment: My vlookup looks like this: (VLOOKUP(A4,'Sheet2'!A4:A465,1,FALSE)).